# DTC Soft Close Slider Replacement?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, drawers

One of the sliders on one of the cabinets in our kitchen has been bent (kid fell on it). I've searched for "DTC 533 soft close slider" (DTC 533 can be seen on the slider below) to try and find a replacement, but the results I get back are all over the place.

What exactly should I be searching for in looking to replace this? Is DTC an actual brand (I found this [DTC website](https://en.dtcdtc.com/product/drawerslides_magicmove-en.html) that would imply yes, but I don't see how to actually buy anything from them)? What does 533 in this stand for? I'm just not sure what information I need to be assessing terms of finding a replacement that matches the damaged part as closely as possible

Some images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A 3-second search for 'dtc 533' yields plenty of results (the first from Amazon). What's the problem? Get the correct length and the right-hand side (if buying only one).

Comment: Yes I've looked at these. It's not clear to me what I should be paying attention to, though, since none of the results actually say anything about DTC. 

E.g. this is the top result from Amazon:

https://www.amazon.com/Mounting-Concealed-Runners-Brackets-Instructions/dp/B09133256Z/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=dtc%2B533&qid=1620762927&sr=8-5&th=1

Is this equivalent to what I'm trying to replace?

Comment: If the design doesn't match exactly, just get any similar pair of 533mm (21") rails. Depending on the age of yours, you may not find identical models.

Comment: And judging by the Alibaba results you may have to order from China for the exact part.

Comment: isherwood, not trying to give you a hard time, just want to make sure OP hears a counterpoint... I think you're recommending what I wrote about as the last ditch option. I would try the other two before attempting to find a match. imo, drawer slides are one of those things where doing what you can to stay exactly the same is worth it. A drawer with different slides out of the whole set is likely going to close/open at different speeds, "feel" different, sound different, and may sit different and extend at different lengths. The oem's website shows a map of distribution hubs in north america.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean, the results are all over the place and what looks like direct replacements may not ship to the US if you could even afford it. I know it's weird to say this, but you will need to call the manufacturer of the cabinets, if you know the brand of cabinet, or if not you should contact the drawer slide manufacturer and ask them to help you find a replacement, you'll want to ask for contact information for their closest distributer to you. For special order hardware is a bear, have patience and sometimes you just have to call around and find the closest contractor (like a casework shop) that carries the brand. Sometimes "closest" can be on the opposite side of the country.

To give yourself a head start in talking with them, go to their website, use the drop down for products, click on the the magic-move (i think but could be d-motion), and then scroll down until you see the web view option to view their catalog. See if you can find your specific product in there or in one of the other product line's catalogs. (sorry, but you'll have to do the legwork here).

If you've got the patience, you can pull the top and bottom sections of the slide apart, and hammer it back close enough to it's original shape. If you're picture is a good representation, it doens't look very bent. You might try clamping it to a block of wood with the bent section hanging off bit by bit and work your way gently tapping it back into relative position.

Your last best bet is to take your slides around locally and compare to other brands of slides... you'll want to look for something that will hold the drawer in the same position. You are not likely to find a slide you can mix and match with the existing closers. This is more about finding something that you can mount in place of the existing hardware and have the cabinet fronts not look like something is off.

Comment: I've reached out to the cabinet manufacturer to see if they have any input (looks like they have a local distributor). If that doesn't pan out I'll try the OEM. Thanks for the suggestions, will come back to mark this as the answer after a little more time to see if anyone else has thoughts.

Comment: If you're up for it/vaccinated, and you don't get the response you want on the phone, try going down there on a Monday at like 2pm and see if you can just talk with one of the guys back from lunch. Bring your's along, they might take pity on you and reward you for the effort... depends on the company.

Comment: Contacting the cabinet maker ended up being the right answer here. They handed me a new set of hardware free of charge. Lucked out that they had a location nearby

Comment: Glad to hear it my friend