# What kind of soft close clip is this?

Tags: drawers

This is a soft close clip, but I don't know what kind it is.  Does anyone know where I can get more of these?

[image: soft close clip]

Comment: Related, with reasonable suggestions in comments: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/224028/dtc-soft-close-slider-replacement?rq=1

Comment: Is that for a door or a drawer?

Comment: It is from a drawer